# Install xdebug on El Capitan with homebrew

Tags: php, homebrew, xdebug, osx-elcapitan

Dumb question I think, but I have PHP 5.6.14 running on El Capitan.

I have installed xdebug with

```
brew install php56-xdebug
```

But there is no mention of xdebug in phpinfo

phpinfo reveals:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path:  /etc
```

When I run brew install php56-xdebug again, I get

```
homebrew/php/php56-xdebug-2.3.3 already installed
```

So I'm guessing that brew has installed xdebug on a path (where?) which is for a different version of PHP which I'm not actually running.

Can somebody help me understand what brew has done, and how I can configure the version of PHP that I'm running to include xdebug.

Comment: if it makes a difference, my loaded php config file was "none", but I've just made a copy of /etc/php.ini.default as as php.ini, and now phpinfo reports my loaded config file is /etc/php.ini. Might my xdebug installation have failed because I didn't have this config when I installed xdebug?

Comment: If anyone is reading this on macOS 10.12 Sierra, I found [this comprehensive guide](https://getgrav.org/blog/macos-sierra-apache-multiple-php-versions) to installing multiple PHP versions, with Xdebug, opcache, version switching, etc. Very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so I fixed this. Any comments welcome on whether I did it right.

1) Found where the brew install of php is using

```
brew info php56
```

This reports:

> To enable PHP in Apache add the following to httpd.conf and restart Apache:
>
> LoadModule php5_module    /usr/local/opt/php56/libexec/apache2/libphp5.so

Update version of php loaded by apache:

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/httpd.conf
```

Replaced

```
LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
```

with

```
LoadModule php5_module /usr/local/opt/php56/libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
```

Comment: You forgot to mention to enable debugging with xdebug.remote_enable = On

Answer (score 2):

For those who use different version of php type in terminal

--> ***brew search xdebug***

and choose yours version.

after installing your version of xdebug you've to active it by placing the installed extension path to your php.ini file.

print your ***phpinfo()*** and look for "***Loaded Configuration File***".

Open the file shown for "Loaded Configuration File" ( mine is ***/etc/php.ini*** ) and paste extension path anywhere you like.

for me the xdebug installed extension path is "***/usr/local/Cellar/php56-xdebug/2.5.1/xdebug.so***"

so i pasted {***zend_extension="/usr/local/Cellar/php56-xdebug/2.5.1/xdebug.so***"}.

restart your apache server and check your **phpinfo()** for **xdebug**, thats all.